# Joe Breeze HiteRite altenative... ideas before I get hacking!

Tags: seatpost

I think the old HiteRite seat dropper springs are excellent for cost and simplicity, but of course they are like hen's teeth now. 
I've been looking at torsion spring suppliers and adapting seat clamps and collars to make one (actually a few, as I have some pre-orders :) but JUST before I get hacking, does anyone know of an alternative that's still in production, or a common hack/mod to make one?

Added as requested: here's an advert for one where you'll see what it looks like and how it works:

[image: 80s HiteRite advert]

Cheers!
Ben

Comment: It sounds like you know a bit about HiteRite already - could you include some more information/explanation of what you're looking for/pictures of them for the uninitiated? It will help expand the accessibility of the question and maybe get an answer from someone other than a retro-fan.

Comment: Here's an article about some complicated expensive modern versions of the same thing: http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/04/bikes-and-tech/deja-vu-ideas-before-their-time_283499/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an extensive search, it seems there isn't a device anywhere near as simple that's still in production.

Comment: Yep. If you haven't found a good source for torsion springs yet: http://www.mcmaster.com/#torsion-springs/=lzuwgy

Comment: I would try item 9287K266 or item 9287K264 - they're both pretty beefy, they're under $7 USD, they're stainless, and there is enough spring leg length to bend loops like in the advert. You can probably find the rest on that website for $20 total (a stainless bolt clamp 5462K44 and some misc nuts and bolts...) Post pics if you do rig one up!

Comment: Thanks for the research! I'll let you know how it pans out.

Answer (score 2):

Many people do seat posts that  achieve this - have a search on google for "Dropper seat post", All of the current models are almost certainly more reliable and easier to use than a simple spring, and can be activated while riding. The fact you cannot find any like the HiteRite is probably the effect of what we now refer to as Darwinism - not bad in it's time, but things have moved on since 1984.

Answer (score 0):

Get hacking.  This would be fantastic for couples (like us) who own a cargo bike.  You end up raising and lowering the seat post every time the other person rides the bike (which is often).  The cheapest reasonable dropper posts are something like $150 and HEAVY, where this would be awesome.